# Count sheets in another worksheet, copy/paste values in all sheets

Tags: excel, count, copy-paste, vba

I've been looking on-line for an answer for this, but can't seem to find anything useful.  Or at least I can't put it together.

Issue:

Have Excel file (fileA) which links to another Excel file (fileB) which contains data, each cell is linked. FileB is frequently updated with new data.

In a separate Excel file (FileC) I have VBA which performs the following:

1. Copies fileA to new folder
2. Renames fileA in new folder to new name FileD
3. Copy/paste all sheets to fixed values (no more links) (FileD)
4. Renames fileD again, this time adding today's date to file name (FileE)

So File A + FileB + FileC are located in one folder.
FileD located in another folder.

Running the VBA goes fine for the bullet points 1, 2 and 4 without any problem.
But I can't get bullet point 3 to work.

From what I can tell, to perform the count of sheets and perform the copy/paste to values the workbooks needs to be open. But I do not want to have to open and close the file (FileD), so this needs to be programmed.

All I can find for the copy/paste function has to do with active workbooks.

I currently have the following VBA, and need this to include a open/close part of the workbook, located in another folder, so path and filename needs to be specified etc. But all attempts from my side have been in vain.

Appreciate any help I can get.

```
Private Sub workbook_open()
Application.Visible = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Call Copy_FilesImport

Application.Visible = True
Application.Quit
Application.ActiveWindow.Close savechanges:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
End Sub
Private Sub Copy_FilesImport()
Dim fso1 As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim FileExt As String

FromPath = "I:\Path1"
ToPath = "I:\Path2\"

Dim FilName As String
FilName = "FileA.xlsx"

If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    FromPath = FromPath & "\"
End If

Set fso1 = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If fso1.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
    MsgBox FromPath & "Error message"
    Exit Sub
End If

If fso1.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
    MsgBox ToPath & "Error message"
    Exit Sub
End If

fso1.copyFile Source:=FromPath & FilName, Destination:=ToPath
Call Renamefiles1
End Sub

Private Sub Renamefiles1()

Dim sName As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim fol As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fol = fso.GetFolder("I:\Path2")

For Each Fil In fol.Files
If InStr(1, Fil.Name, "FileA.xlsx") <> 0 Then
sName = Replace(Fil.Name, "FileA", "FileD")
Fil.Name = sName
End If
Next

Call Value

End Sub

Private Sub Value()
Workbooks.Open Filename:=("I:\Path2\FileD.xlsx")
Dim file As String
file = "FileD.xlsx"
For i = 1 To Workbooks(sName).Worksheets.Count

Sheets(i).Select

Range("A1").Select
Sheets(i).Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, 
Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Next i
Workbooks("FileD.xlsx").Close savechanges:=True

Call Renamefiles2

End Sub



Private Sub Renamefiles2()

Dim sName As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim fol As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fol = fso.GetFolder("I:\Path2")

Dim datoformat As String
datoformat = Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")


For Each Fil In fol.Files
If InStr(1, Fil.Name, "FileD.xlsx") <> 0 Then
sName = Replace(Fil.Name, "FileD", "FileD_" & datoformat)
Fil.Name = sName
End If
Next
MsgBox "Succes"
End Sub
```

Comment: do you get any errors? and what ecaxtly do you need? file folder part as well? or just copy part(bullet 3 as you say)

Comment: I need bullet 3,, I have more VBA before and after this module that copies/moves file to new folder, and renames twice.

Comment: ..continued before the second rename I need this vba module to locate file (in another folder / path) and to copy+ paste values on each sheet in the workbook so the new file do not have any active links. all the vba is located i a seperate file (xlsm)

Comment: Sorry forgot. I get an error issue with "For i = 1 To Workbooks(sName).Worksheets.Count" and Error "run-time 9 Subscript out of range" Have checked file name several times and file  name is correct.

Comment: is sName assinged a value? or maybe you intended to put "file", and put sName mistakenly?

Comment: See I thought there was something off there, copied from an on-line example, I tried to use file instead of sname in the "for i =" statement, setting it as a string value, diden't work for me and vice versa sname iso file also diden't help. I appreciate anything you might be able to do to fix this, I have to leave the site now and won't be able to be back before monday. so lack of comments from now to monday is not egual lack of interest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you should post all the code, so i can see other possible lack, like if you're opening the file before traversing the sheets. Maybe before sending the whole code, you might want to have a last look to see whether you open the file before manipulating it.

Comment: Okay. here is the full VBA,

Comment: Full VBA added in orignal question

Comment: Let me know if there is anything else you need?

Comment: ok, i have the solution now. since you start the for loop specifying the workbookname in the sub named Value, you should also include it before worksheets in the loop. so it is supposed to be "Workbooks(file).Worksheets(i).Select" instead of "Worksheets(i).Select" and "Workbooks(file).Sheets(i).Cells.Select" instead of "Sheets(i).Cells.Select". By the way you should also change the "sName" to "file".

Comment: You have so absolutely made my day. Just ran a test, and it does exactly what it is supposed to. So thank so much for the assistance. I figured it needed a few adjustments to work.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: no problem. don't forget to upvote please :)

Comment: would love too, new to the system, what to do?

Comment: well actually i'm relatively new as well, i think you should click the up button next to my answering 'comment'. if you cannot do it, i may put the solution as an answer. so you can click the up button next to my answer instead of comment

Comment: there is no UP button next to your answer for me to see!

Comment: it is the upward arrow button over 0 :)

Comment: Yep, can't use that, as I can't vote on my own question. It won't allow it.

Comment: no no, dont try it on your question, try it in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

ok, i have the solution now. since you start the for loop specifying the workbookname in the sub named Value, you should also include it before worksheets in the loop. so it is supposed to be

```
Workbooks(file).Worksheets(i).Select
```

instead of

```
Worksheets(i).Select
```

and

```
Workbooks(file).Sheets(i).Cells.Select
```

instead of

```
Sheets(i).Cells.Select
```

By the way you should also change the "sName" to "file".